# Derived class and Derived field. Change a few or all properties values

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

Using C# 10 and Net 6 I have (simplified code):

```
public class DefaultsBase {
  public Int32 Repeats { get; set; } = 10;
}

public abstract class StrategyBase {

  public abstract String Name { get; }
  public abstract DefaultsBase Defaults { get; }

}

public class MonthlyStrategy : StrategyBase {

  public override String Name => "Monthly Strategy";
  public override MonthlyStrategyDefaults Defaults = new MonthlyStrategyDefaults();

  public String Street { get; }

  private class MonthlyStrategyDefaults : DefaultsBase {
    public Int32 Window { get; } = 20;
  };

  public MonthlyStrategy(String street, Action<MonthlyStrategyDefaults> defaultsConfiguration)  {

    defaultsConfiguration(Defaults);
    Street = street;

  }

}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is:

1 - Create Strategy classes that derive from StrategyBase;

2 - In each Strategy being able to create a StrategyDefaults derived from DefaulstBase.

3 - Use an Action in constructor to change a few or all Strategy's Defaults including the ones on DefaultsBase.

I am not sure if my implementation makes sense and I am also getting the errors:

```
public override MonthlyStrategyDefaults Defaults 
> The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item 

public MonthlyStrategy(String street, Action<MonthlyStrategyDefaults> defaultsConfiguration)
> Inconsistent accessibility: 
  parameter type 'Action<MonthlyStrategy.MonthlyStrategyDefaults>' is 
  less accessible than method 'MonthlyStrategy.MonthlyStrategy(string, Action<MonthlyStrategy.MonthlyStrategyDefaults>)
```

How to do this?

Comment: Change from private to public MonthlyStrategyDefaults see if it helps?

Comment: `public override MonthlyStrategyDefaults Defaults` must be `public override DefaultsBase Defaults`. Otherwise it's not overriding the parent prop.

Comment: `MonthlyStrategyDefaults` => I'd make that a public class `MonthlyStrategyConfig` with default values pre-set. And I doubt I would include it in the base class. Or maybe, I'd make that a Generic BaseClass so, I could do `public class MonthlyStrategy : StrategyBase<MonthlyStrategyDefaults>`. But honestly, _most probably_ I'd just use an IStrategy interface rather than a base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### first error

to override a property in the base class, it should has the same **type** and name

```
public override MonthlyStrategyDefaults Defaults = new MonthlyStrategyDefaults();
```

change it to

```
public override DefaultsBase Defaults = new MonthlyStrategyDefaults();
```

#### second error

In the public method `MonthlyStrategy` you try to give it a private class as a parameter `Action<MonthlyStrategyDefaults>`  ... how the caller object  would instantiate or deals with a private class! ...
you have three solutions

1. Change the accessibility for `MonthlyStrategyDefaults` and make it public
2. Or you can configur based on base class, `Action<DefaultsBase>` instead of `Action<MonthlyStrategyDefaults>`
3. Or make all configuration internally